# Error when Attempting to Install Plugins

Tags: plugins, error, installation

I keep getting this error whenever I try to install a plugin.

[image]

Not sure how to troubleshoot / resolve this.

Basically, I need the Contact Form and CKEditor plugins.

Setup: I'm running AMPPS with PHP 7.1, Apache and MySQL.

Comment: Ahh, weird... seems like I'm able to install plugins now...

I navigated to Settings > Plugins and saw the two plugins I clicked on on the Plugin store. Clicked on install under the gear dropdown and both plugins installed like a charm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what is causing this error but I've got the same problem for plugins install and update. To avoid this annoying error page, I prefer to install/update plugins via composer.

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer require {plugin name}
```